# Visual Studio 2013 databases from template missing

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio-2013

I've been passing my ASP.NET 4.5 MVC project through git for a while now, but at some point in the past couple of pushes and pulls between a couple computers, the SQL database which contained all of the Identity models has disappeared and when I try to register an account I get a page that says:

```
Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyProject\MyProject\App_Data\aspnet-MyProject-20150629050117.mdf' as database 'aspnet-MyProject-20150629050117'.
```

and the source error highlighted as:

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

This is the database which comes with the template and is run from LocalDB.
Is there any way to restore or recreate the database from the MVC system?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem:

.mdf database files are excluded from repos if you use the standard Visual Studio project .gitignore file. Therefore pulling will never result in an available database.

You have to generate a create script for your db to be run after pull so you can regenerate the tables.

This doesn't preserve your data, so if you absolutely must have persistent data in your repo db, then look into database version controlling.